# Dynamically apply Change event listener to each selection element

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to simplify the following code so I do not have to add a function for every single question? My goal is to return the value of each selection to a JS variable that matches the name of the HTML ID for that selection element. I have a lot of questions here and there's got to be a better way than declaring a function for each selection question.

```
let question1Var
let question2Var

const question1 = document.querySelector('#question1Var');
const question2 = document.querySelector('#question2Var');

question1 .addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  question1Var= event.target.value;
});

question2 .addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  question2Var = event.target.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a common class to all questionVar ids - lets say "`question`"

```
let questionVariables = {};

let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("question"); //this will store all the elements

for(let i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
{//for each item bind the change event
    elements[i].addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        questionVariables[event.target.id] = event.target.value;//store the value in a json having id as the key
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! To get this to work i had to change [this.id] to [event.target.id], does that make sense?

Comment: yes I think event.target.id would be better option - I will update the answer as well

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good solution to register **addEventListener** on all of the elements. Say you have 100 elements. Would you listen  for change on all of them at the same time?

---

A better solution would be to listen for **keypress** or **keydown** on *document*. And then narrow it down to inputs with an if statement.

```css
let questions  = {}

let inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input.question")
let pre = document.querySelector("questions")
document.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
  const input = event.target;
  if (input.classList.contains("question")) {
    const index = [...input.parentNode.children].indexOf(input)
    questions["question" + (index +1)] = input.value
    console.log(questions)
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <input type="text" class="question col-12" name="">
    <input type="text" class="question col-12" name="">
    <input type="text" class="question col-12" name="">
    <input type="text" class="question col-12" name="">
    <input type="text" class="question col-12" name="">
    <input type="text" class="question col-12" name="">
    <input type="text" class="question col-12" name="">
    <input type="text" class="question col-12" name="">
    <input type="text" class="question col-12" name="">
    <input type="text" class="question col-12" name="">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

---

You may use `input.name` instead of `"question" + (index +1)` should it has distinct name.